# limit of a sequence 2

Tags: real-analysis

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{1+2+3...+n}n+\frac{2-n}{2}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n+1}2+\frac{2-n}2\right)=\frac32$$

is it right?
The suggested solution in my book is $-\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: `left(` and `right)` delimiters might help format your post better.

Comment: Use the fact that $\displaystyle \sum_\limits{k=1}^n k=\dfrac12n(n+1)$. Then simplify, and combine the fractions, don't plug in the limit. You should have your answer. There seems to be a problem with the solution in the book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are right. In fact, the sequence is constant, that is
$$\frac{1+2+\cdots+n}n+\frac{2-n}2=\frac32\;\forall n\in\Bbb N$$

There must be some typo in your book.

Comment: For some reason, unknown to me, two people have downvoted this answer. I have double checked it and I can't see where the problem is. I'd like to know how to improve this answer.

Comment: I think some of the downvotes are given by those who have given a close vote to the question. Some people (myself not included) try to judge questions and answers on same basis. +1 to compensate for silent downvote.

Answer (score 1):

We know by Gauss sum formula that $$ \sum_{j=1}^{n} j=\frac{n(n+1)}2$$

This means that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{1+2+3+\cdots+n}n+\frac{2-n}{2}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{\sum_{j=1}^{n} j}n+\frac{2-n}{2}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac 1n\cdot \frac{n(n+1)}2+\frac{2-n}2\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n+1}2+\frac{2-n}2\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{(n+1)+(2-n)}2\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac32={\color{red}{\frac{3}{2}}}$$